# How to attach a subnet to a server without individually adding each IP?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have a dedicated server and I ordered a `/29` subnet for this server which contains 6 IPs.

I can add those IP addresses one by one to the server `(/etc/network/interfaces)` like this and I become able to connect to the server from them;

```
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.2
...
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.6
```

So I basically need to add each IP like this but I wonder if there's a way to attach those IP addresses to my server without having to add each IP to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file?

I tried this but it didn't work;

```
iface eth0 inet static
  192.168.1.1/29
```

This only allowed me to connect through `192.168.1.1` and not through `1.2`, `1.3` and so on.

Comment: I doubt it would work (and would not recommend it even if it does), but what happens if you use 192.168.1.7/29 - ie the broadcast address?

Comment: It only enables access from that address.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is impossible

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted?

Comment: Don't know either :/

Comment: Maybe because of the implication that it _would_ be possible with dynamic IPs? (It's not possible in any case.)

Comment: This answer is (unfortunately) correct. Only scripting could make this possible. It’s not worth it, though.